# GROUP_CONCAT and JOINS with multiple lookup tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple series of joins with a `GROUP_CONCAT` that need to be performed on a number of tables and lookup tables.

```
    Table unit:
    +---------+-----------+
    | unit_pk | unit_name |
    +---------+-----------+

    Table unit_outcome:
    +----------------+--------------+
    |unit_outcome_pk | unit_outcome |
    +----------------+--------------+
    
    Table discipline_outcome:
    +----------------------+--------------------+
    |discipline_outcome_pk | discipline_outcome |
    +----------------------+--------------------+
    
    Table unit_outcome_discipline_outcome_lookup:
    +-------------------------------------------+-----------------+-----------------------+
    | unit_outcome_discipline_outcome_lookup_pk | unit_outcome_fk | discipline_outcome_fk |
    +-------------------------------------------+-----------------+-----------------------+

    Table unit_unit_outcome_lookup:
    +----------------------------+-----------------+---------+
    |unit_unit_outcome_lookup_pk | unit_outcome_fk | unit_fk |
    +----------------------------+-----------------+---------+
```

So, if `unit_fk = 1` and `discipline_fk = 5` in the corresponding lookup tables, the results should look like the following given the test data in the fiddle (link below):

```
+---------------+-----------------------+
|unit_outcome 1 | discipline_outcome 10 |
|               |                       |
+---------------+-----------------------+
|unit_outcome 2 | discipline_outcome 7  |
|               |                       |
+---------------+-----------------------+
|unit_outcome 3 | discipline_outcome 1  |
|                 discipline_outcome 8  |
|               | discipline_outcome 9  |
+---------------+-----------------------+
```

What I have so far is the following query, which just gets results for `unit_outcome -> discipline_outcomes`, without filtering on the `unit` and the `unit_unit_outcome_lookup` tables, e.g. for `unit_fk = '1'` as well as the discipline_fk:

```
SELECT unit_outcome, 
GROUP_CONCAT(discipline_outcome SEPARATOR '|') AS discipline_outcomes
FROM unit_outcome u
LEFT JOIN unit_outcome_discipline_outcome_lookup l ON u.unit_outcome_pk = l.unit_outcome_fk
LEFT JOIN discipline_outcome d ON l.discipline_outcome_fk = d.discipline_outcome_pk
WHERE d.discipline_fk = '5' 
GROUP BY unit_outcome
```

I need to incorporate those two tables in the above query to only have unit_outcomes that correspond to a given unit_fk as well as the discipline_fk.  Not sure how to do this though.

[db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ajhn5pi3xYgMrvxs8dM5gJ/6)

Comment: `WHERE d.discipline_fk = '5'` would mean `discipline_outcome` 2 and 3 would not be pulled

Comment: Discipline outcomes 2, 3 and 4 belong to discipline 1 in the test data in the fiddle.  So they would not be included in the results if discipline_fk = 5...

Comment: @Mech, I have updated the question to more accuruatly show the results in the test data given unit_pk = 1 and discipline_fk = 5

Comment: if you want data for `unit_pk = 1` then why you're not joining with `unit_unit_outcome_lookup` and applying a where clause? further more if `unit_outcome_fk` and `unit_fk` is one-to-one then above table is not required but if one to many then `unit_outcome_discipline_outcome_lookup` table should have `unit_unit_outcome_lookup_pk` instead of `unit_outcome_fk`.

Comment: Can you achieve it without using `GROUP_CONCAT` first?

Comment: I need to add the other lookup tables to the query...I'm not sure how to do that. Have you looked at the fiddle?

Comment: Change WHERE to AND

Comment: Can you explain why in the expected results you want `discipline_outcome 3` for `unit_outcome 1` and `discipline_outcome 2` for `unit_outcome 2`?

Comment: Those are the corresponding values in the unit_outcome_discipline_outcome_lookup table See fiddle at https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ajhn5pi3xYgMrvxs8dM5gJ/6

Comment: Yes but for `discipline_outcome 3` the `discipline_fk` is 1 and not 5 which is your condition.

Comment: @forpas  You are correct, discipline outcomes with pks 2 and 3 do not belong to discipline 5.  I have amended the expected results in the question to correspond to the TEST DATA in the fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must join all the tables with INNER joins like this:

```
SELECT u.unit_outcome, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(d.discipline_outcome ORDER BY d.discipline_outcome_pk SEPARATOR '|') AS discipline_outcomes
FROM unit_outcome u
INNER JOIN unit_outcome_discipline_outcome_lookup l ON u.unit_outcome_pk = l.unit_outcome_fk
INNER JOIN discipline_outcome d ON l.discipline_outcome_fk = d.discipline_outcome_pk
INNER JOIN unit_unit_outcome_lookup uu ON uu.unit_outcome_fk = u.unit_outcome_pk
WHERE d.discipline_fk = '5' AND uu.unit_fk = '1'
GROUP BY u.unit_outcome
```